# How do I return a list of errors on a registration page?

Tags: php, validation

Basically I wish to write my registration page in such a way that errors (such as invalid username, short password, too long username, invalid email, etc.) are returned (at the same time) when user is redirected back to the same page.

I have often seen a lot of websites that have this:

> There are X errors in the data you submitted:
>
> 1. Username is too short
> 2. Password is too short
> 3. Etc. etc.

And these errors are returned when the user submits the form and is redirected back.

I thought of returning the errors via numbers in `$_GET` however I'd like to avoid this. And I also would like to avoid using JS/AJAX and `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Are you using an application framework for your app?

Comment: No. Everything is hand coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a library:

```
if ($_POST)
{
    $form_helper = new FormHelper();

    $form_helper->validate($_POST["username"], "username");
    $form_helper->validate($_POST["password"], "password");

    if (! $form_helper->notifications())
    {
        // Process form.
    }
}

// Show errors if necessary when rendering the form.
```

Without a library:

```
$errors = array();

if ($_POST)
{
    // Validate username by hand (let's pretend it passes).
    // Validate password by hand (let's pretend it fails).

    array_push($errors, "The username or password is incorrect.");

    if (! $errors)
    {
        // Process form.
    }
}

// Show errors if necessary when rendering the form.
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be typically done using `$_SESSION`, which you don't want to use for some unexplained reason. They are typically called *flash session* as once the information has been showed to the user, that portion of the session is destroyed.

You *could* use cookies and manage it yourself, but I'd stick to using the session. Be sure to remember cookies can be easily tampered with from the end user.

Comment: The reason i don't want to use JS/AJAX is because i don't know it. The reason i don't want to do it via $_SESSION is because while extremely improbable a more techy user could have disabled them...(immediate webpage failure) and why not via GET? because imho it's too ugly but it would work immediately and always

Comment: @dikidera A techy user can disable cookies (the main method a session is associated with a user), but not disable a session itself.

Comment: So sessions ($_session) cannot be disabled by end user(thus not being able to view them if disabled)?

Comment: @dikidera They can disable cookies which means the session can't be tracked. You *could* pass the session identifier via a GET param, but IMO that's way too clunky & ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Make the page submit the form to itself, and you won't have to return anything. You just need to make the code handles both the case where the user comes to the page for the first time and the case where data has been submitted.

Comment: This violates [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) though. No one enjoys those *Do you want to submit a form again?* messages.

Comment: @alex: Sure, but only if the submission was unsuccessful. Also: how do you pass in current (possibly invalid) values for the form fields if you do PRG at this point? No one enjoys those forms where you get a bunch of error messages and an empty form to fill from scratch.

Comment: I use the `$_SESSION` myself for that.

Comment: Assuming your the code looks like `if(success){ //render form }else{//display form}`, putting `header("Location: http://site.com/path/to/this/page", 302);` in the success branch will stop the "Repost form" prompt if they refresh the confirmation page. They will still get the message if they refresh the form itself, but the data would not be submitted twice as the form submission is not successful.

Comment: @alex: That's fine. Anyhow, I reasoned that since the OP doesn't want sessions and doesn't want GET params (not to mention the ugliness)  they 're probably running out of options already -- so POSTing to self would probably be acceptable.

Comment: @Jon I agree. But I am wondering why the OP doesn't want to use `$_SESSION`. Because cookies can be disabled?

Comment: @alex: Not sure really. I just took the requirement as stated.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't a lot of options here.

I'd pass it in $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is good practice (or even possible with php), but I've had good results by returning error messages in a table and then letting some JavaScript code display them.